# javascript character, word, & space count function

Tags: javascript, string, function

I am trying to create a javascript function that counts the characters, words, spaces, and average word length in a string and returns those in a single object. Initially I had the character count working, but when adding in the word count, I have gotten lost. Can I declare a single function with other functions inside to do this? Also, I can't seem to get the first 2 parts working, but I'm not sure what is wrong with this code:

```
var charLength = 0;
var count = function(text) {
  var charLength = text.length;
  return charLength;
};
var wordCount = 0;
for (i = 1; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text.charAt(i) == " ") {
    wordCount++;
  }
  return wordCount + 1;
  console.log("Characters: " + charLength + " Words: " + wordCount);
}
var text = "Hello there fine sir.";
count(text);
```

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/minditorrey/z9nwhrga/1/

Comment: Did you know a function stops when it encounters a `return`? It makes no sense to have code after such a statement.

Comment: Where is the rest of your fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9nwhrga/2/):

```
function goforit(text){
  var charLength = text.length;

  var spacesCount = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == " ") {
      spacesCount++;

    }

  }
  var wordsArray = text.split(" ");
  var totalWordLen=0;
  for (j = 0; j < wordsArray.length; j++) {
    totalWordLen = totalWordLen + wordsArray[j].length;

  }  
  var wordCount = spacesCount+1;
  var average = totalWordLen / wordsArray.length;
  var outputString = "Characters: " + charLength + " Words: " + wordCount + " Spaces: " + spacesCount + " Average: " + average;
    alert(outputString)
  console.log(outputString);
}



var text = "Hello there fine sir.";
goforit(text);
```

Comment: This is immensely helpful! Many thanks from a total Noob!

Answer (score 2):

Currently you have intermingled functions and non-functions. I think you meant to include the word counting inside `count`, but currently it exists outside of there. Moving that code directly into `count` will be troublesome however, since you can't have multiple return statements inside a function. You will need to keep track of the measurements in local variables, and then construct something to return that contains all of the values. Like this, for example:

```
//var charLength = 0; You have a global and local variable, omit this one
var count = function(text) {
  var charLength = text.length;
  var wordCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { // declare i with var, start at 0
    if (text.charAt(i) == " ") {
      wordCount++;
    }
  }
  return { 'charLength': charLength, 'wordCount': wordCount };
};

var text = "Hello there fine sir.";
console.log(count(text)); // add a way to see the results
```

To take this a step further, you could simplify the word counting to:

```
text.split(' ').length
```

So your new `count` function would look like:

```
var count = function(text) {
  var charLength = text.length;
  var wordCount = text.split(' ').length;
  return { 'charLength': charLength, 'wordCount': wordCount };
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm in the early stages of learning and I wasn't sure how to do multiple things in a single function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check this (or here in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/tazayaqige/edit?js,console):

```
var count = function(text) {
  var charLength = text.length;
  var wordCount = text.split(" ").length;

  console.log("Characters: " + charLength + " Words: " + wordCount);
  return { wordCount: wordCount, charLength: charLength };
}

var text = "Hello there fine sir.";
count(text);
```

You are trying to define two functions, but actually you define count function, but the other one wordCount is not defined as function. Just statements, and there is a return statement, etc. Anyway, check the above code, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make this a class see this link on how to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Once you have a class drop the return statements and make the variables global to the class. This was you can call the class name and then pull out the variable required for display.

You can get a word count in various ways. Personally I would use str.split(' ').length; If you then assign this to a variable you would be able to loop over it gather stats on word length and come up with your averages etc.